# I cloned my Windows on SSD and I can't delete the EFI partition on HDD

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, bsod, efi

I recently bought a M.2 SSD (Seagate BarraCuda) and cloned my Windows 10 (build 2004) on it from my HDD using Macrium Reflect. All good with the process, I changed the boot order from the BIOS to put the SSD first (and the only one as well) and after a few successful boots, I deleted Windows from my HDD.

Since the day following the cloning process I've been getting the DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION bluescreen when I boot for the first time each day (I don't get it if I shut down and boot again immediately after), and tried everything to get rid of it, except the firmware update, which I want to use as a last resort.

One thing I noticed is that I cannot delete the EFI partition from the HDD while I can delete the SSD one. Now I'm assuming that occurs because the one from the HDD is in use by Windows, while the other isn't. And since I know EFI partitions are crucial for OS boot, I suspect this as a possible cause for the bluescreen.

[Disk 0 (HDD) EFI Partition, as seen in Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq6KA.png)

[Disk 1 (SSD) EFI Partition, as seen in Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QEZa.png)

Another suspicious thing I noticed is via DISKPART in CMD. None of the EFI partitions have the YES status on Required, which I find really strange.

[Disk 0 EFI Partition details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDxaO.png)

[Disk 1 EFI Partition details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nquU.png)

If my assumption about which EFI partition is in use is correct, how can I change this? If not, can someone, please, enlighten me about what is going on?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot delete the EFI partition on the system disk, for obvious reasons, it's requited by Windows.  You can delete the EFI partition from a non-system, but if you do that, you won't be able to boot to that disk.  Why do you want to delete the EFI partition exactly?

Comment: To make sure Windows is booting from SSD only. And I just found out the Boot Device is on the HDD via System Information (HarddiskVolume5). I guess it should be on the SSD. My Windows is installed on the SDD though, only the Boot Device is the problem.

Comment: You should be able to change the boot order within the UEFI settings.

Comment: I did that after cloning Windows, I put the SSD first. But I kept the HDD as a boot option for safety reasons, and now I deleted it. Hopefully this will solve the DSP_WATCHDOGS_VIOLATION BSOD. If not, I'll have to try and update my SSD firmware.

Comment: You can delete an unused EFI partition, but from personal experience, I know the existence of an unused EFI partition is not the cause of a `DSP_WATCHDOGS_VIOLATION` BSOD.

Comment: Will keep you updated if it happens again tomorrow. But even if not, shouldn't I be able to delete the supposedly unused partition via Disk Management?

Comment: Also, I apologize for writing DSP instead of DPC, but I don't think it counts much.

Comment: Doesn't matter the BSOD in question isn't caused by unused EFI partitions.

Comment: Seems like deleting the HDD boot option solved it. 3 days in and I didn't get the BSOD once.